# centOS on virtualbox "Couldn't resolve proxy

Tags: hadoop, networking, proxy, centos, yum

so i have installed `sandbox`(running centOS) from `hortonworks` on a `virtualBox` 
with network config>>>  `bridged network`
and i edited the `bashrc` to export `http_proxy` and https_proxy as

```
export http_proxy=http://host_name:port
export https_proxy=https://host_name:port
```

i can do `ping` 
but when i us `yum` or `wget` or `curl` i get

```
14: PYCURL ERROR 5 - "Couldn't resolve proxy 'host_name'"
```

can someone tell me please what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as an answer to my question in case if somebody have the same problem ..
i just replace the host_name with the ip address and it work just fine